# How to pass a visibility token to the bitflags! macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm using the [bitflags](https://crates.io/crates/bitflags) crate. I want to automatically generate some other implementations for my types, so I tried to call the `bitflags!` macro from another macro. This worked fine until I wanted to be able to handle a visibility token.

I tried the following code.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6cb8d295c7cae96559c62074c84ae90e)

```rust
use bitflags::bitflags;

macro_rules! my_bitflags {
    (
        $(#[$outer:meta])*
        $vis:vis struct $name:ident: $ty:ty {
            $(
                $(#[$inner:ident $($args:tt)*])*
                const $flag:ident = $value:expr;
            )+
        }
    ) => {
        bitflags! {
            $(#[$outer])*
            $vis struct $name: $ty {
                $(
                    $(#[$inner $($args)*])*
                    const $flag = $value;
                )+
            }
        }
        
        // other implementations on $name here
        // 
    }
}


my_bitflags! {
    pub struct Flags: u32 {
        const A = 0x1;
        const B = 0x2;
        const C = 0x4;
    }
}
```

I expected this to work but I get the following error

```
error: no rules expected the token `pub `
```

Is this an issue with the `bitflags!` macro? Or am I passing the visibility token incorrectly?

Comment: I never used that crate, but seems like a [`yes`](https://docs.rs/bitflags/1.2.1/src/bitflags/lib.rs.html#336), this is the issue in bitflags crate. It for some reason matches explicitly, probably that's where it breaks? Maybe it would be worth making a pull request? Visibility token is optional and it wouldn't be a breaking change.
 The very bizarre part to me is that error explicitly has a space after `\`pub \``.

Comment: I'd say it is a bug in `bitflags`. It looks like it does not expect a `vis` but a combination of a literal `pub` and a few other tokens (`vis` is recent addition to the macro syntax). And by passing an explicitly parsed `vis` when it expects a plain token `pub` it gets confused and fails to compile.

Comment: Currently `bitflags` crate requires rustc 1.20, but `vis` in macros was added in 1.30. Maybe fixing the crate will bump the minimum required version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$vis` in `bitflags!` [is defined](https://lukaslueg.github.io/macro_railroad_wasm_demo/) as a token tree (`tt`), not as visibility (`vis`). Visibility was only "recently" introduced to rustc and the `bitflags!` macro stays backward-compatible by not redefining `$vis`.

You need to change `$vis:vis` to `$vis:tt` in `my_bitflags!` so it can expand into `bitflags!`.